# Laravel run code when new user registrated with default registration code

Tags: laravel

Im running a laravel 6.9 application with default authentication/registration.

I want to maintain the default registration process but i want to run a curl command if a user has registered.
Is it possible to hook into the default registration process and extend it with extra code?

Comment: Something like an [Observer](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#observers), when a user is created?

Comment: @kerbh0lz if you post it as an answer I will accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observer is good point in code where you can, well, observe if user is just registered but good place to put additional code after user has been registered is event/listener group. There is already Registered event set in EventServiceProvider so you would need to put additional listener beside one already set there (for sending email to newly registered user if opted). To have all sorted next steps should be followed (disclaimer: I am taking that you use all default auth code so far):

First copy `registered(Request $request, $user)` method from `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php` trait to default `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController`

```
/**
 * The user has been registered.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
{
    //
}
```

So you would override that piece of default code which is meant to stay intact (as should every code from vendor directory).

Then, you would need to create listener. In `App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::listen` array, add one more class into value array so it should looks like

```
/**
 * The event listener mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $listen = [
    Registered::class => [
        SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
        \App\Listeners\FooBarBaz::class,
    ],
];
```

Don't bother for not having created class already, next artisan command will do that for you:

```
php artisan event:generate
```

Now, in `\App\Listeners\FooBarBaz::class` you can make your custom code related to new user:

```
namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;

class FooBarBaz
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  Registered  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(Registered $event)
    {
        // $event->user is accessible here
        // 
        // this method should return void, it is just executed
    }
}
```

Now, back to registered method of RegisterController. Here you would need to initiate event:

```
/**
 * The user has been registered.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
{
    event(new \Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered($user));
}
```

And you are done. 
I wanted to show you use of already lot of prebuilt code although Observer is also good place. But also for calling event; I wouldn't put more code than this `event(new \Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered($user));` line into `UserObserver::created(User $user)`. Whole part with event/listener is very good and decoupled now. Of course, you can make even custom event not using default Illuminate's one, just set that new `key => value` into EventServiceProvider.

[Events](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/events)
[Observers](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#observers)

Comment: @SvenvandenBoogaart Actually, you should skip duplicating registered() method since it is invoked by framework itself and just adding Listener would do the job done.